# Mean.io 0.5.5 Heroku deploy issues

Tags: heroku, mean-stack, mean.io

Trying to deploy a mean.io app to Heroku and running into all sorts of challenges

[Here are a few things I tried (Github Issue)](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1409)

- First I had to increase my dyno memory to 1GB+ or the app would
  crash.
- Next I had to resolve the [missing modules](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1409#issuecomment-167837647) and tell heroku not to cache `node_modules`

  - `npm i -S ms kerberos connect-modrewrite`
  - `npm update --save`
  - deploy
  - `heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`
- Finally I had to [set the CPU count to 2](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1409#issuecomment-171740207) because the app still took too
  much memory.
- `heroku config:set CPU_COUNT=2`

The app fails because aggregated.js is missing bower files from the packages/custom/ folders. How do I run `mean postinstall` on heroku?

Comment: CPU_COUNT=2 was perfect for big memory issues I was having on Heroku. Thanks for that.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for posterity's sake.

## Resolving bower dependency issues

I had some custom packages that were created before the new package scaffold system had `bower install` as a postinstall command. Add this to any custom package that relies on bower dependencies.

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "bower install"
  }
```

Now pushing to heroku runs npm/bower in each package directory and all is well.

Comment: And now 9 months later I find myself ripping bower out of my projects ;)